# How to handle mutiple users in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing database in mysql  for one site having four diffrent users as follows.
1.Admin
2.Businesses
3.Investors
4.Personal

I have created four diffrent tables for each type of users because they have different columns. And also  I created one table named user roles like.

User_roles => rol_id & rol_name

I have given rol 1 as admin, 2 as businesses and so on. Now i need to create one commen user_login table which carries the user name & pass word of all the above type user. I am confused about how to make the relation between all these four tables and user_login table?

Comment: what about using `groupes` and `roles` tables . so you will have 4 tables , 
`users`,`groups`,`roles`,`group_roles`

Answer (score 1):

**Model**

You need only 3 tables.

1. user: id, username, password
2. role: id, role_name
3. user_role: user_id, role_id

The column user_id is a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) pointing to the column id of the user table.
The column role_id is a foreign key pointing to the column id of the role table.

The advantage of this model is that if you want to create a new role, you only have to add a row in the role table and do not need to modify your model.

**Examples**

User table:

```
id   username   password
1    sangam     password
2    Muur       password
```

Role table:

```
id   role_name
1    Admin
2    Business
3    Investor
4    Personal
```

Retrieving the list of admins:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u, user_role ur, role r
WHERE u.id = ur.user_id AND ur.role_id = r.id
    AND r.role_name = 'Admin';
```

Adding a new role:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE role(role_name) VALUES('New Role Name');
```

Adding the Business role to the user sangam:

```
INSERT INTO user_role(1, 2);
```

Or :

```
INSERT INTO users.role_user(user_id, role_id) VALUE(
    (SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = 'sangam'),
    (SELECT id FROM role WHERE role_name = 'Business')
);
```

Comment: The question said there would be different fields per user role, where does that fit in to your examples?

Comment: You are right, I did not understand that at first. I corrected my answer, thanks to you.

Comment: yes correct, I must need these four tables because their table structure is diffrent from each others. I just need to attach all four table with user_login table along with their login deatils, so  when any record is deleted from one of these four tables then their respective record in user_login table also need to delete.

Comment: What are the other columns? In some cases, it is fine to have all columns in one table, some with NULL values. The inconvenient is to have NULL values, the advantage is that it is easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You'd most likely use [foreign keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp), and create a table that contains user IDs and role IDs, which can then be used to lookup role + user data in the associated table.

Comment: I have four primary keys from respective user ex: admin_id, business_id, investor_id, personal_id. So do you mean I use these primary keys as foreign key in that table?

Comment: Yep. I'd recommend just having one "users" table though, with the irrelevant columns empty though. This way, you don't have to make changes 4x, and looking up user's information becomes very easy. Additionally, you'll save yourself a ton of time / code / headache when checking which role a user is before grabbing their information.

Answer (score 0):

#### Table USER_ROLES e.g. Admin, Businesses, Investors, Personal

*USERID | USER_ROLES_ID*

#### Table USER_LOGIN

*USERID | USERNAME | PASSWORD*

#### Table USER_ROLE_DEFINED

*USER_ROLES_ID | ROLE_NAME*

Find out what User Role is for Username

> SELECT ul.username, ud.role_name FROM USER_LOGIN ul, USER_ROLES ur, USER_ROLE_DEFINED ud >WHERE ul.username = "adam" AND ul.userid = ur.userid AND ur.user_roles_id = >ud.user_roles_id;

The logic is there, whether it works... you have to test it yourself.

As commented by others, this is a three table version. Yes, two tables has its advantage as well.